# How to kill a thread running in the background - Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have situation where for every hit from a user a thread from a thread pool will be running in the background. So when multiple users hits there will be multiple threads running in the background. Now when one user refreshes their browser I want to kill that thread running the particular user's browser window so that the thread goes back to the thread pool.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the obstacle to your doing this exactly? What's stopping you from coding what you want? It seems quite straighforward.

Comment: Are you using own thread pooling or some existing solution like [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)? You should provide some example code so we know what has to be done.

Answer (score -2):

Hopefully this helps.

{jstack JAVA_PID}

Gives you list of threads with process id and thread id which are run in the jvm.

The thread id is hexa format. Map this output to top command which is mentioned below.

top JAVA_PID

Comment: Question does not indicate thread killing should be performed manually by OP. That would be very inconvenient.

Comment: Yes you are right. That is why i  kind of said hopefully. This is how i used to take of handling threads from behind the scene.